# Where to find the general definition of i2c "master_xfer" function?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

`struct i2c_algorithm` has function pointer template for `master_xfer` for i2c bus implementation. Where can I find the default function routine of `master_xfer` in linux kernel source.? 
Please someone guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is i2c-gpio.c file in /driver/i2c/busses/. In that we are filling `master_xfer` function with `bit_xfer`. It does bit banging implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What master_xfer is set to depends on your platform and bus.  Look under drivers/i2c/busses/ to find where this function pointer is set.  Note that it could be set to NULL.

An example of where it is set is in drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-pxa.c:

```
static const struct i2c_algorithm i2c_pxa_algorithm = {
        .master_xfer    = i2c_pxa_xfer,
        .functionality  = i2c_pxa_functionality,
};
```

Also look at include/linux/i2c.h:

```
struct i2c_algorithm {
        /* If an adapter algorithm can't do I2C-level access, set master_xfer
           to NULL. If an adapter algorithm can do SMBus access, set
           smbus_xfer. If set to NULL, the SMBus protocol is simulated
           using common I2C messages */
        /* master_xfer should return the number of messages successfully
           processed, or a negative value on error */
        int (*master_xfer)(struct i2c_adapter *adap, struct i2c_msg *msgs,
                           int num);
        int (*smbus_xfer) (struct i2c_adapter *adap, u16 addr,
                           unsigned short flags, char read_write,
                           u8 command, int size, union i2c_smbus_data *data);

        /* To determine what the adapter supports */
        u32 (*functionality) (struct i2c_adapter *);
};
```

:

```
 * An i2c_msg is the low level representation of one segment of an I2C
 * transaction.  It is visible to drivers in the @i2c_transfer() procedure,
 * to userspace from i2c-dev, and to I2C adapter drivers through the
 * @i2c_adapter.@master_xfer() method.
 *
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. Was useful... but suppose if I am using I2c-gpio, where to refer please.

Comment: @kzs It looks like the bit banging i2c-gpio interface uses only the i2c_adapter struct, not i2c_algorithm.

Comment: No Peter, Actually it does uses, there is i2c-gpio.c in the same path. in that we are filling master_xfer function with bit_xfer. thanks for the reference.